# Copying .rtf text into the body of an email with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, rtf

I have an AppleScript application which creates an email (in Mail.app) with attachments from the options I choose through dialogs. The text templates are stored in `.rtf` format so non-programers can alter the text templates to their wishes.

I am able to create an email from a `.txt` plain text file, but when I import an `.rtf` text file it imports the formatting commands, which I don’t want in the mail.

Here is an example of a `.rtf` import into an email:

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf360
>   {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica-Light;}
>   {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
>   \pard\tx560\tx1120\tx1680\tx2240\tx2800\tx3360\tx3920\tx4480\tx5040\tx5600\tx6160\tx6720\ql\qnatural\pardirnatural
>
> \f0\fs24 \cf0 technology mail for english speakers\

Here is part of my script:

```
-- Import the .rtf file and store content in the mycontent variable    
set mycontent to (read "/Users/kiara/Desktop/mailer/technology/tech-en-content.rtf")
…
…
-- create mail from values stored in variables
tell application "Mail"
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:mysubject, content:mycontent}
    tell content of theMessage
        make new attachment with properties {file name:this_file} at after last paragraph
    end tell
end tell
```

Is it possible to import formatted text from `.rtf` files into a new mail without the formatting codes (I choose rtf because mostly bold and color are used to format text)?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach:

```
set the clipboard to (read "/Users/kiara/Desktop/mailer/technology/tech-en-content.rtf" as «class RTF »)

tell application "Mail"
    activate
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:"mysubject"}
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Mail"
        repeat until focused of UI element 1 of scroll area 4 of window 1
            keystroke tab
        end repeat
        keystroke "v" using command down
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Just saved my bacon, been fighting Mail's stupid Templates "feature" for ages.  Thanks so much!

Comment: This seems to be the only way now, as it looks like Apple removed the ability to set the content as html. See the final comments to the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think Mail sends an email as either plain text or HTML, not RTF, so you need to send email as HTML not RTF. Note there's a trick to sending an HTML email with Mail via AppleScript. For some reason you can't set the visible property of the new message to true. It won't work if you do.

Here's how this can help you. You can use the command-line tool `textutil` to convert the RTF to HTML and then send it as an email. Notice I use `tidy` in the command to make sure the HTML code is clean.

So all you need to do is put the receiver's email address and a subject in this script and run it:

```
set emailAddress to "someone@somewhere.com"
set theSubject to "My converted rtf to html"

set rtfFile to choose file with prompt "Choose the RTF file to email as HTML:" without invisibles
set theHTML to do shell script "/usr/bin/textutil " & " -stdout -format rtf -convert html " & quoted form of POSIX path of rtfFile & " | /usr/bin/tidy -b -utf8"

tell application "Mail"
  set newMessage to make new outgoing message at end of outgoing messages with properties {visible:false}
  tell newMessage
    make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:emailAddress}
    set subject to theSubject
    set html content to theHTML
    send
  end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Good one – I wasn’t aware of the undocumented “html content” (good reminder one should always check object properties instead of relying on the dictionary). Two remarks, though: setting `visible:false` isn’t necessary– omitting that property will work too (anything but `visible:true`, one suspects); and using `tiny -bare` will not handle characters outside the ASCII range gracefully – besides  exiting non-zero (which will error out `do shell script`), it leaves you with the infamous “ fÃ¶rmattingâ€¦” versions of UTF-8 text. Using `tiny -raw` or `tiny -utf8` will give better results.

Comment: Thanks for the comments kopischke. I have updated the code to use your suggestions regarding tidy. That's a good and necessary improvement.

Comment: Checked the mail in raw source view and found "Content-Type: text/html" so yes you where right with rich text ending up as HTML. I hardcoded a path to a rtf file and deleted the send command because my users must be able to check the mail a last time before sending. The problem I now face is that the mail shows up without the content in the body. Do you know how to make content show up in the body?

Comment: If you want to see the email before it is sent I think you'll have to save the invisible email first and close it, so it becomes a draft. Then you can open the draft from the drafts mailbox. I don't have any code for that but it should work.

Comment: Great idea just had to add "save newMessage" and "close newMessage" in the "Mail" Block. Now the mail get's saved into drafts and you can see the text in the mail. But when I open the mail, I only see the text but no attachments. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: After the new attachment line I can see that my console show missing value. Could this be the source of the error?

Comment: I just checked... it still works. Not sure why you say otherwise. You must have changed the code or added something, because it works as-is.

Comment: Apparently, the property "html content" does not exist anymore (in Mac OSX Yosemite).

Answer (score 0):

adayzdone answer works for me - more or less.
under Mac os X 10.15.6 , Mail 13.4 the scroll area is at another position / index.
And instead of using `keystroke tab` to get the content-Area an alternative way is to

```
set value of attribute "AXFocused" of UI element of scroll area 1 of window 1 to true
```

if you need to find the scroll area or identify other UI elements - you might want to use

```
on FindScrollAreas()
    set Indices to {}
    set the clipboard to "hello World"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Mail"
            activate
            set i to 1
            repeat with UIElement in UI elements of front window
                -- button, text field, scroll area, static text
                if class of UIElement is scroll area then
                    set end of Indices to i
                end if
                set i to i + 1
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
    return Indices
end FindScrollAreas
```

and there is also the fantastic approach in using Automator **watch me do** to get the menu items:
[see this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315086/applescript-ui-scripting-and-click)
(you have to copy-paste the Events from Automator to some text-Editor to get some corresponding applescript)

and there is Xcode -> Xcode(menu) -> Open Developer Tool -> Accessibility Inspector - but i find it hard to transfer info to applescript

hope that helps, best -tom