# AppleScript; Copying a HTML .rtf file into the body of Email

Tags: html, email, applescript

What I want to do is the exactly same as this from the Link below

```
set the clipboard to (read "/Users/kiara/Desktop/mailer/technology/tech-en-content.rtf" as «class RTF »)

tell application "Mail"
    activate
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:"mysubject"}
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Mail"
        repeat until focused of UI element 1 of scroll area 4 of window 1
            keystroke tab
        end repeat
        keystroke "v" using command down
    end tell
end tell
```

Reference from: [Copying .rtf text into the body of an email with AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658483/copying-rtf-text-into-the-body-of-an-email-with-applescript)

But it does not work on my Mac condition OS X Mavericks

Please anyone give me how to compose a HTML Email with AppleScript.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do won't work. Whatever you paste into an email message is pasted as text. It just doesn't work. You can try it but it won't work. The reason you're having trouble is because it's "scroll area 1" in the latest versions of Mail, not 4.

But there is a way it will work. Mail has something called "html content". So if you have html code then you can set the "html content" of a message to that html code. There's 1 caveat though. It seems to be a bug, but if you set the html content of a message then for some reason you can't see it. You can send it and it will work properly... but you can't see it. As such I usually set the visible of the message to false and just send it with applescript.

Anyway, since you have an rtf file you'll need to use the command line tool "textutil" to convert the rtf into html code so you can put the html into the message.

Try this. Set a receiver and subject first. Good luck.

```
set rtfFile to "/Users/kiara/Desktop/mailer/technology/tech-en-content.rtf"
set receiver to "somebody@email.com"
set theSubject to "This is the subject"

set htmlCode to do shell script "/usr/bin/textutil -stdout -format rtf -convert html " & quoted form of rtfFile

tell application "Mail"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message at end of outgoing messages with properties {visible:false}
    tell newMessage
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:receiver}
        set subject to theSubject
        set html content to htmlCode
        delay 0.5
        send
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advices. I have tried this code which seems to work, but I think my HTML code would be different in the circumstance. My HTML code is starting from this:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Newsletter</title>
<style type="text/css">
 td {
  font-family:Courier,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size:12px;
  color:#fff;
 }
 
 p {
  margin:0 0 12px 0;
 }
</style>
</head>


In this code, how can I set it into the body of Mail with AppleScript?


Thank you!