# Applescript: How to paste RTF on clipboard to email on Apple Mail?

Tags: applescript, rtf, pandoc

I made an Alfred workflow to convert my markdown (.md) notes to RTF and automatically add to my clipboard using pandoc in a bash script. Now that my notes are on the clipboard I want to offer the option to paste the RTF in the clipboard into a new email with the Alfred workflow. Alfred runs osascript so I have been using the Script Editor on Mac to create my script. I have this so far:

```
set clipContent to the clipboard

tell application "Mail"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:"[NOTES] "}
    make new cc recipient at newMessage with properties {address:"EmailAddress"}
    set newMessage's content to clipContent
    activate
end tell
```

But I get this error message

[Mail got an error: Can’t make {«class RTF »:«data RTF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0swqL.png)

Any suggestions on what is happening?

Thanks

M

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying .rtf text into the body of an email with AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658483/copying-rtf-text-into-the-body-of-an-email-with-applescript)

Comment: The class of the `content` property is `text` (plain text).

Answer (score 2):

[@vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian) is partly correct in that, although *Mail*'s AppleScript dictionary states that the `content` property of an `outgoing message` is `rich text`, it appears that one can only set the property using plain text.

I think you're best best to achieve what you want is to use GUI scripting in order to get the system <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (paste) the rich text directly into the text area of the email on your behalf.  It's not ideal, but it works:

```
tell application "Mail"
    activate

    set newMessage to make new outgoing message ¬
        with properties {visible:true, subject:"[NOTES] "}

    make new cc recipient at newMessage ¬
        with properties {address:"EmailAddress"}
end tell


tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Mail" to tell ¬
        window 1 to tell ¬
        scroll area 1 to tell ¬
        UI element 1 to set ¬
        focused to true

    keystroke "v" using command down
    keystroke return
end tell
```